# SQL Server Native Client compatibility

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-native-client

Our whole team is using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 and we have a new member joining our team but he is only able to install SQL Server Native Client 2012. Will there be any compatibility problems or issues that may arise from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine, but SQL Native Client drivers are all old.

The latest versions of the [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15) and [OleDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20OLE%20DB%20Driver%20for%20SQL%20Server.%201,OLE%20DB%20Driver%20for%20SQL%20Server%20%28MSOLEDBSQL%29%20) drivers are now separate downloads.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The new member will mostly be using it to run basic select queries and also connecting to powerbi. I tried convincing my supervisor to move away from native client but they dont have a say on it as well.